# Java load library 'Can't find dependent libraries'

Tags: java, opencv, gstreamer, loadlibrary

I have compiled the OpenCV from source with GStreamer support for Java, everything was OK.
**But** in below two cases I got this problem:

1. When I copy the generated JAR and DLL files to the other machine
   (although I have everything installed in both of machines, such as
   GStreamer, and all necessary libs and software).
2. When the build process finished and the JAR and DLL files were
   generated successfully, an also before restarting everything works well, but when
   restarted the computer and run again this problem is happening, the same as when I
   used the JAR and DLL files on the other machine.

In the past (compiling OpenCV without GStreamer) I did not get the problem. But now why this problem is going to happen, I have all in the classpath and system path and environment path. GStreamer can be found anywhere in the machine because I have added all it's (DLL, and Libs) paths to the system path.

Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and solve it by installing the gstreamer-ffmpeg in the new machine

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```